# How to force actual authentication workflow in ASP.NET core middle ware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to inject some application context that is based on authenticated user into the execution context so that business/service layers can use it transparently. I am planning to use middleware for setting up the same. Sample code in startup is

```
app.UseAuthentication();

// my custom middleware
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // use context.User to build the application context 
    // ...

    // inject into execution context
    // ...
}

app.UseMvc(..)
```

Unfortunately, HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated remains false in my custom middleware. Actual authentication based on JWT Tokens gets triggered when MVC Authorization filters are hit. So how can I overcome this issue? Is there a way to know when actual authentication stage is finished (similar to global.asax in classic ASP.NET pipeline) or how can I enforce authentication handlers in my middleware. I tried playing with extension methods `context.AuthenticateAsync` to force the construction of actual user principal but in vain.

Another issue that I hit is carrier for my application context. I earlier chose `AsycLocal<T>` but found out that what I set in my middleware is not available at downstream code. So currently, I am using HttpContext.Items to carry my application context which will work but I am curious to know why `AsycLocal<T>` failed. Is it not guaranteed to be carried over execution context in ASP.NET pipeline?

As requested, ConfigureServices part

```
    // Add Azure AD JWT Bearer Token support for API authentication
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
                       .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
    ...
    // Add Azure AD OpenID authentication support for interactive UI
    services.AddAzureAdV2Authentication(Configuration);
```

Also found need for adding schemes in policy for multiple schemes to work

```
        // Add MVC with authentication/authorization
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme,
                    AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
```

Finally, in my middleware, I was trying to enforce authentication using snippet such as

```
     if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
          if(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(HeaderNames.Authorization))
          {
               await context.AuthenticateAsync(
                   AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme);
          }
          else
          {
              // issue OpenID challange
              ...
          }
       }

      // here, I still found context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated false
```

Comment: @Kahbazi, yes it appears to be the case. But I was under impression that user principal will be set up when authentication handler runs. Any idea when exactly that happens in pipeline

Comment: @Kahbazi, I thought AuthenticateAsync plugs into Authentication Middleware that in turn triggers actual handler based on scheme. I am curious how MVC Authorization is triggering auth middleware...

Comment: So Authentication middleware is only setting principal for default scheme. But then it does get set later in MVC authorization pipeline - do you know where?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? My problem is a bit different, but I'm trying to do something similar to the Middleware bit, call a method to authenticate.

Comment: @Quails4Eva, there is no solution in .NET core 2.2 version. I had finally used a global authorize filter that set up my application context. It worked because need of app context was controllers beyond. You can also try context.ChallengeAsync to trigger say OpenID challange.

Comment: For .NET core 3.0, authorization middle-ware is re-vamped and I will migrating away from global authorization filter.

Comment: Just as an update, now I am using global authorization handler in .NET 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.UseAuthentication()` only tries to authenticate with the default scheme and I'm guessing JWT Tokens is not your default. You can try `context.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` to authenticate with jwt scheme.

Comment: you are right... I am using multiple authentication schemes - OpenID and JWT Bearer. I had already tried `context.AuthenticateAsync(particularSchemeName)` based on presence of authorization header but it doesn't seem to be working.