# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ASP.NET 5 - need to force it to be rechecked?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, razor-pages, .net-5

ASP.NET 5 Razor Pages with Cookie Authentication.

On Chrome on an iPhone, when I sign in with remember me enabled, then open a page:

Source: https://github.com/djhmateer/password-postgres

All is fine. If I close the mobile browser (double click then swipe up), then open it again I'll see:

[image]

Even if I do a page refresh it doesn't work. I can see the request hitting the server:
[image]

If I go to another page eg back to /Tier1RoleNeeded with Authentication on it all starts working.

If feels like I need a way to manually force authentication to be checked when the app goes back to /Account/Login as it is being sent back here wrongly.

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false.

From [How to force actual authentication workflow in ASP.NET core middle ware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922078/how-to-force-actual-authentication-workflow-in-asp-net-core-middle-ware) I have tried

```cs
public async Task OnGetAsync(string? returnUrl = null)
{
    
    // I want people to be able to come to the login screen and be automatically redirected to /Tier1RoleNeeded
    // Clear the existing external cookie
    //await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    // can we catch if already authenticated?
    if (User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Log.Information("Authenticated!");
        ViewData["Message"] = "Authenticated so redirect to /Tier1RoleNeeded";
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Information(" just before AuthenticateAsync");
        // maybe chrome on an iphone has just been opened
        // force authenticate try
        await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

        ViewData["Message"] = "User.Identity.IsAuthentication is false - Not Authenticated so please login";
    }

    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
}
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Dave , `Even if I do a page refresh it doesn't work` what do you mean? What is the expected result of the page?

Comment: Hi @Rena - I'm expecting to be already authenticated with the existing cookie. Interestingly I'm seeing the same behaviour in https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authentication/cookie/samples/3.x/CookieSample yet working in the templated (file new project) version. Am digging into both versions now.

Comment: Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0 is what my code is based on.

Comment: Hi @Dave, If you use cookie authentication without Identity, you need mention the configuration named IsPersistent  which is used to implements the remember me function. But you need know that if you close the browser app, the cookie lifetime is finished. Besides, if you just close the page without closing the app, it will maintain the cookie. This is true by default and you could not change it because of the cookie lifetime.

Comment: @Rena - thank you. You put me on the right track and it was the SameSiteMode setting.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it worked when setting the SameSiteMode Cookie to Lax in `Startup.cs\Configure`

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// If we use strict then will have problems on iPhone Chrome coming back to the site
// and being logged out.
//app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict });
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax });

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0#cookie-policy-middleware

https://github.com/djhmateer/only-authentication is source code demostrating this scenario.

And my own blog which I've updated for this scenario https://davemateer.com/2020/10/21/cookie-authentication-in-asp.net-core-3.1

I'm still mystified why Strict fails on iPhone Chrome, yet works on desktop.